# Building a single likelihood for the sum of two events

Tags: statistics, binomial-coefficients, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

Consider an unknown number of adult deer, $N$, which can be split into two groups - males, $M$, and females, $F$, where $N = F + M$. These adults were hunted during the year (a lethal form of sampling without replacement), with each group having its own individual-level probability of being killed by a hunter, $p_f$ and $p_m$, respectively. For example, male deer in Michigan have a 40% of being killed by a hunter during the hunting season while females only have a 16% chance of being killed. The number of adults that were killed can be denoted as $m$ and $f$, respectively.

I want to build a likelihood for the total number of adults, $N$, given that I know $p_m$, $p_f$, $m$, and $f$, to be used in a larger joint likelihood. If I were interested in building a likelihood for the two different *groups* of adults, I could write:
$$L(M \mid p_m,m) = \binom{M}{m} \cdot (p_m)^{m} \cdot (1-p_m)^{M-m}$$
$$L(F \mid p_f,f) = \binom{F}{f} \cdot (p_f)^{f} \cdot (1-p_f)^{F-f}$$
What I want, however, is
$$L(N \mid p_m,p_f,m,f) = \text{?}$$
The full likelihood already has a large number of parameters to estimate, so I'd rather just have a single parameter for the total number of adults, as opposed to having a separate parameters to estimate for males and females. Basically, the likelihood equation cannot contain $M$ or $F$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is puzzling that you would choose a binomial model when sampling is without replacement and kill rates are above 10%. // I guess you want to estimate $N.$ But that raises the issue how you can know kill rates without knowing population sizes. // I'm wondering if there is additional information lurking in the background that would make it possible for this to become a more or less standard hypergeometric 'capture-recapture' model for estimating population size.

Comment: Hi @BruceET,
This is just a small part of the full joint likelihood. Another source of data is the number of hunters, which helps to estimate kill rates. The more sources of data that get included, the more parameters can be estimated. Any thoughts on if I can estimate kill rates, how I can combine these two likelihoods?